# Does Hibernate 4.3.x support JTA 1.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, jta

The maven dependency for Hibernate 4.3.x is JTA 1.2. For license reasons we would prefer to use JTA 1.1 from Geronimo.

However, I cannot find any clear indication of whether JTA 1.1 is compatibale with Hibernate 4.3.x. I see that in Hibernate 5.x the dependency has changed back to JTA 1.1

Can anyone confirm whether Hibernate 4.3.x is compatible with JTA 1.1?

Comment: If you use Geronimo you don't need Hibernate, Geronimo use OpenJPA.

Comment: We just want to use the Geronimo JTA implementation. We don't use Geronimo itself.

Comment: I did some strange mix too. But the goal of projects like geronimo, wildfy... are to provide a full stack tested. Mixing some stuff of one in another is not trivial. But as answered @spandlerb you can build your own version of hibernate with JTA 1.1 dependency. Or just exclude in your pom JTA 1.2 dependency and get explicitly JTA 1.1... and testing a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could find is this snippet from the build.gradle file [found here.](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3.11.Final/build.gradle)  It is for 4.3.11.final  and looks like a workaround if it is not in the version you currently have you could attempt to add it.

```
instruction 'Import-Package',
                // Temporarily support JTA 1.1 -- Karaf and other frameworks still
                // use it.  Without this, the plugin generates [1.2,2).
                'javax.transaction;version="[1.1,2)"',
                // Tell Gradle OSGi to still dynamically import the other packages.
                // IMPORTANT: Do not include the * in the modules' .gradle files.
                // If it exists more than once, the manifest will physically contain a *.
                '*'
```